# How to get stat (item_scraped_count) using Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get the total count number of scraped items but I am always getting error

```
from scrapy.stats import stats

class MySpider(Spider):
  name = "myspider"
  start_urls = ["http://example.com"]
  #Other Code


def close_spider(self, spider):
   stats.set_value('item_scraped_count')
```

I always got this error 
"Scrapy.stats already obsolete use crawler.stats instead"

I tried different code and searched all over the internet but I cant get the right answer, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Good Now I just use this from https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html

```
def __init__(self, stats):
    self.stats = stats

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(crawler.stats)
```